# showing a function of two variables is not uniformly continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x) = \frac{x+y}{xy}$

I see that the function is not uniformly continuous because neither $1/x$ or $1/y$ is uniformly continuous.  I think I need to show that when $| x_1-x_2 |<\delta$, $| f(x_1)-f(x_2) | >\epsilon$, but I am not sure how to choose the points $x_1$ and $x_2$... Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the domain? Away from the axes? One quadrant? The idea is similar in any case, this function is "bad" near the origin.